# cocos2d problem with device

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

my application use cocos2d and all work fine in simulator but when i try to build my app for device i've the next error:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTextureCache", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLView", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCSprite", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCLayer", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCSpriteFrame", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCLayer", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTexture2D", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCDirector", referenced from:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScene", referenced from:

How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried rebuild ?

Comment: clean and rebuild and try again.. delete the app on ur device as well..

Comment: tnx, but i've tried rebuild, clean all target delete, all but does't work :(, now i've tried to add the library not like a static library and now on device work but on simulator does't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple suggestions for this problem:

1) Do you still have your cocos2d libraries still intact?  You need to have them linked to your target application for it to work.  make sure you have libcocos2d.a, libCocosDenshion.a, and other libraries you need to build your application.

2) Make sure you have libz.dylib somewhere within your project.